# Add/Delete entry in join table with checkbox

Tags: jsf

I have the entity customers (represents table in database):

```
    @Entity
    public class Customer implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        private int nr;
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name = "ACCES",
                joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_NR", referencedColumnName = "NR")
                },
                inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ROOMID", referencedColumnName = "ROOMID")
                }
        )
        private List<Room> rooms;
    }
```

And I habe the entity room (represents table in databse):

```
@Entity
public class Room implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private int roomId;
    private String building;
    private String roomnr;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rooms")
    private List<Customer> customer;
```

The tables have a many to many relationship that is working.

On my JSF-Page I have a table that shows all customers. With a selectBooleanCheckbox I want to create/delete (checked/unchecked checkbox) entries in the generated join table.

```
<h:form>
            <h:panelGrid rendered="#{!empty roomController.allRooms}">
                <h:dataTable value="#{raumController.alleRooms}" var="r" border="1">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Raum-Id" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{r.raumId}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Building" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{r.building}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="roomnr" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{r.roomnr}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Access" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="this.form.submit()" value="#{customerController.AccessCheck(r.raumId)}" immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{customerController.accessChanged}">
                            <f:attribute name="raumId" value="#{r.raumId}" />
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

How can I make it work that every customers has its own entry if he has access to a room and the right state is displayed on the page?

Comment: In the table all rooms of the database are shown. Each entry has a checkbox that has to show if the current customer has access to the room in this row or not -> entry in the join table between customer and room.

Comment: Just maintain a bidirectional relationship using those inverse collections (`private List<Room> rooms;`, `private List<Customer> customer;`).

Comment: If I use a commandButton it's no problem for me to add rooms to a customer, but I don't know how to do it with the checkbox. This should be bidirectional: http://pastie.org/9865325